# Creating Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm just starting to create a Chrome Extension. I have read a few tutorials. But how to create one that handles the page events. I would like to highlight the text in the browser and change the color. I have all the HTML and jQuery code already written, but I don't know how to put it together as a Chrome Extension
Any help appreciated.

So I have these codes below:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Select text",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with selected text.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background" : {"page":"background.html"},

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


            function getSelectedId(){
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('div').click(function(){

                    var name = $(this).attr('id');
                    $("#result2").fadeIn();
                    $("#res").html(name);

                    console.log(name);

                });
             });   
            }



        $('body').click(function(){getSelectedId();});


});
    </script>
    <style>

        #res{font-size: 2.5em;}
        #result2 {width: 200px;height: 150px;background-color: gray; color: white;position: absolute; display: none; text-align: center;
            -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 21px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 21px #000000;
box-shadow: -1px 0px 21px #000000;
border:solid 1px #404040;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="bbb">gggggg</div>

<div id="result2">
    <p>The ID is:</p>
    <p id="res"></p>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

so what I want is that when I click on any div, either the popup.html or somewhere on the page I assume background.html will fadein that div "ID". How do I do that?

Sorry, but this is my first Chrome Extension attempt :(

Comment: Read [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

Comment: thanks, I have read it already. But still confused. I just want to call .js file that interacts with the window or browser. Even just simple click with an alert :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at [content-scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), these JS scripts are packaged with your extension and can be used to interact with the elements on a 3rd party website.

You define the sites that will trigger your content scripts in the manifest by declaring them in `matches`. In `js` you tell the extension what scripts to invoke.

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

In this example if we include `myscript.js` in the root of the extension we could have something like this that would fire an alert when we land on Google.com.

```
alert("We're now on Google.com");
```

I think that should get you off the ground!

Comment: I think you need to start again from the beginning. Background pages shouldn't contain UI and are designed as a way to communicate between the different parts of your extension. Background pages and popup.html will require message passing logic (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and is quite an advanced concept to start with. Stick to the basics for now (i.e. my example) and work from there when you are more familiar with what extensions can do.

Comment: ok, so what would be the simplest way to show an element ID once is clicked on and floating somewhere in the browser in a div? I know I can do all these with jQuery. But I would like to do it using extensions. many thanks.

Comment: Or just a simple solution when users hover over the element, then that element ID will popup. Similar to WhatFont extension.

Comment: Have you managed to get the Google example working above. That would be a starting point. You would then just edit myscript.js to capture the mouseover events and display in a floating div. That's really another question though.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have managed to do a few stuff with the popup.html but not to that extend. Here is my post what I'm actually trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173026/jquery-to-chrome-extension any help is appreciated.

Comment: The admins have now closed the link above. I really don't know why. Sometimes it really irritates me how all those rules work. We should be helping each other, right?! So what if it is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. What if I'm doing it just for fun? How do they know what I want out of it? Anyway, whoever is able to help, thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow is a brilliant resource but you need to ask specific questions. Don't ask I want my program to do this, how do I build it. You will get a far better response if you break your problem down and ask specific questions. Imagine if all the questions on here were only related to the questioners very niche problems, how does that benefit the rest of the community? Remember you're asking people to give up their time to help you, be specific and spend time preparing your question. I would recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Firstly, I didn't task anyone to build my program. Sedondly, I have broken down my problems and asked for help or advice. I have even provided pieces of code. All I got was either rejection or some snobby responses.

Comment: Stackoverflow is peer moderated so to close a question several admins need to agree. Try not to take it personally, most users have had questions closed and those with lower ratings attract more scrutiny. I saw your other question and it did seem a little unfair but Stackoverflow can be brutal sometimes! The scope of what you are trying to do here covers many areas of extension development and for anyone to provide a comprehensive answer would take a long time. My advice as before is read the vast body of info on Chrome dev site and break your problem down into smaller chunks.

Comment: Bottom line Stackoverflow may be the wrong place until you have a better understanding of the core concepts with Chrome Extensions http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html